# CSS background-color transition is not working with other transitions

Tags: css, background-color, transition

I have an element that toggles between two classes when the user clicks on it. The two properties that change between classes are margin and background-color.

When I add transition to only one element, either one, the transition works well but when I use both transitions the background-color one does not work. I tried doing individual transitions for each property and combining both properties in one transition but I can't get it to work. When I disable the margin transition, the background-color transition works fine, but as soon as I enable the margin transition again, the background-color transition stops working.

This is my CSS:

```
.switch_Active {
    background-color: $not_selected;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 5000ms;
    -moz-transition: background-color 5000ms;
    -o-transition: background-color 5000ms;
    transition: background-color 5000ms;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: 45%;
    transition: margin-left 0.5s ease;
    width: 20px;
}

.switch {
    background-color: $selected;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 5000ms;
    -moz-transition: background-color 5000ms;
    -o-transition: background-color 5000ms;
    transition: background-color 5000ms;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    transition: margin-left 0.5s ease;
    width: 20px;
}
```

I tried looking up online but I couldn't find any limitations with the transitions. I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Css will take the last defined property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine transitions:

```
transition: background-color 5000ms, margin-left 0.5s ease;
```

If you have 2 equal properties they will get overwritten. Also note that it isn't necessary to give the 2 classes the same transition unless you want different transition between going active and inactive.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid overriding use this. Because CSS will basically takes the lastly defined property.

```css
.switch_Active {
    background-color: $not_selected;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 5000ms,  margin-left 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: background-color 5000ms,  margin-left 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: background-color 5000ms,  margin-left 0.5s ease;
    transition: background-color 5000ms,  margin-left 0.5s ease;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: 45%;
    width: 20px;
}

.switch {
    background-color: $selected;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 5000ms, margin-left 0.5s ease;;
    -moz-transition: background-color 5000ms, margin-left 0.5s ease;;
    -o-transition: background-color 5000ms, margin-left 0.5s ease;;
    transition: background-color 5000ms, margin-left 0.5s ease;;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    width: 20px;
}
```

or simply them like this:

```css
.switch_Active {
        background-color: $not_selected;
        -webkit-transition: background-color,  margin-left 0.5s ease;
        -moz-transition: background-color,  margin-left 0.5s ease;
        -o-transition: background-color,  margin-left 0.5s ease;
        transition: background-color,  margin-left 0.5s ease;
        border-radius: 50%;
        height: 20px;
        margin-left: 45%;
        width: 20px;
    }

    .switch {
        background-color: $selected;
        -webkit-transition: background-color, margin-left 0.5s ease;;
        -moz-transition: background-color, margin-left 0.5s ease;;
        -o-transition: background-color, margin-left 0.5s ease;;
        transition: background-color, margin-left 0.5s ease;;
        border-radius: 50%;
        height: 20px;
        margin-left: 50%;
        width: 20px;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, the first suggestion worked;with the second one, it seems that if I don't  declare the transition for each property individually, the first one will be overwritten.